# How can I keep this Pandas column type as datetime when using MultiIndex?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, timestamp, multi-index

This is so strange I honestly wonder if I am just mis-interpreting things.

I have some code that builds a multi-index from datetime values, but after generating the multi-index, the type has changed to Timestamp. **I would like it to stay datetime.** Why would I care? Well, another part of the code generates a multi-index in a slightly different way from the same datetimes but in that case it keeps the datettime type - so I can't use update between the two DataFrames because the columns are not seen as equal (yes I checked by comparing the values directly).

On to the minimal code example:

```html
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

iterables = [['bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'qux'], [datetime.date(2014, 10, 3)]]
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 4),columns = columns)
```

This gives:

```html
>>> df.columns[0]
('bar', Timestamp('2014-10-03 00:00:00'))
```

Note that the type on the date is now Timestamp, not datetime. Down the other portion of my code it stays datettime (which is the correct chain of events, yes?) and so now they both reference the same date but test as not equal so I can't apply DataFrame.update to push data from one to the other. Unfortunately both paths have strong data-driven reasons why they should be done the way they are.

Any workarounds or solutions come to mind? Or did I miss something obvious and the whole premise is silly (which I won't discount as a possibility here somehow - I'm surprised the datetimes test as not equal to the Timestamps)? Is there an easy way to reach in and change the *second level* types of the multiindex to change those back into datettimes?

edit: Almost forgot: pandas version 0.15.2

Comment: `df.columns.levels[1][0].to_datetime()` will convert the timestamps back to datetime. I can't find away to apply this to the whole level of the index at once. List comprehension will work but i guess it isn't very `pandas`

Comment: `to_datetime()` returns a `datetime`, but it does not modify the caller.

Comment: unutbu, thanks for the further explanation, that makes tons of sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the construction of a `MultiIndex`, the [values get changed into `Categoricals`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/index.py#L3577).

`Categoricals` of `datetimes` [automatically get converted to `Timestamps`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/categorical.py#L258):

```
In [287]: pd.Categorical([datetime.date(2014, 10, 3)])[0]
Out[287]: Timestamp('2014-10-03 00:00:00')
```

but the [`Categorical` of an `Index` does not](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/categorical.py#L249):

```
In [288]: pd.Categorical(pd.Index([datetime.date(2014, 10, 3)]))[0]
Out[288]: datetime.date(2014, 10, 3)
```

Therefore,

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

iterables = [['bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'qux'], pd.Index([datetime.date(2014, 10, 3)])]
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4, 4),columns=columns)
print(df.columns[0])
```

yields

```
('bar', datetime.date(2014, 10, 3))
```

---

Note, the easiest way I know to change the MultiIndex of a DataFrame, is to reassign a new MultiIndex. Thus, if `df` already has a MultiIndex with Timestamps, to convert the MultiIndex to datetimes use:

```
iterables = [['bar', 'baz', 'foo', 'qux'], pd.Index([datetime.date(2014, 10, 3)])]
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterables)
df.columns = columns
```

Comment: unutbu, you're incredible. Just like that my data is back and everything works! I'd been working on it all day and was just digging into categoricals.py but was still probably hours from resolving this. Thanks so much! This isn't the first time I've used one of your solutions.