# Python/Pandas: date objects converted to timestamps in multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

Is there a way to create a MultiIndex using datetime.date object and not have them converted to timestamps?

If I have the following tuples:

```
travel = [('car', datetime.date(2021, 10, 1)),
 ('car', datetime.date(2021, 10, 2)),
 ('car', datetime.date(2021, 10, 3)),
 ('bus', datetime.date(2021, 10, 1))]
```

with the second item in each tuple being a datetime.date object, and I create a multi index:

`ind = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(travel)`

They get converted to timestamps:

`ind[0] = ('car', Timestamp('2021-10-01 00:00:00'))`

If I use it to create a dataframe, I get errors when trying to reference the row:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index = ind, columns = ['distance'])
df.loc[('car', datetime.date(2021, 10, 1))]

KeyError: datetime.date(2021, 10, 1)
```

Yet if I convert it to timestamp there's no problem referencing:

```
df.loc[('car', Timestamp('2021-10-01 00:00:00'))]

distance    NaN
Name: (car, 2021-10-01 00:00:00), dtype: object
```

I've tried re-constructing the index as below, but no luck as the dates are not unique values:

```
dates = [datetime.date(2021, 10, 1),
 datetime.date(2021, 10, 2),
 datetime.date(2021, 10, 3),
 datetime.date(2021, 10, 1)]

df.index = df.index.set_levels([df.index.levels[0], dates])

ValueError: Level values must be unique: [datetime.date(2021, 10, 1), datetime.date(2021, 10, 2), datetime.date(2021, 10, 3), datetime.date(2021, 10, 1)] on level 1
```

The the datetime.date gets converted to a timestamp independently or whether I create the MultiIndex using tuples, or other methods.

Comment: Why would you want to keep datetime.date? That would just be an object Series; you could as well format to string %Y-%m-%d for example

Comment: @MrFuppes Thanks for your question. Two reasons: first I want to use `pandas.dataframe.loc` to slice the dataframe using the list that was used to generate the index itself. `.loc[ ]` doesn't recognize the dates and the timestamps they are converted into as being the same and returns an error. Secondly I'm curious if this is a limitation when creating a multi index dataframe, or if there is a reason why it's like this.

Comment: I just hit this exact problem.  It's a real pain that set_index() happily creates one kind of date and pd.MultiIndex only creates the other! 
 But maybe this helps?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28132668/how-can-i-keep-this-pandas-column-type-as-datetime-when-using-multiindex

Comment: @MichaelTiemann, thanks this seems to be the only way to make it work. Would you like to post it as an answer to this question?